# How to callbacks to another stack ? - Livecode

Tags: livecode

I create Looping video.

I want to use function callbacks to another stack.

Here my code :

```
   start using stack "Widget Project"
   put the duration of player "Player" into tDuration
   put tDuration & ",restartPlayer" into tCall
   set the callbacks of player "Player" to tCall
```

Comment: Please, write what happens if you run this code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use callbacks if you want to execute a script when a movie finishes playing. You can use the `playStopped` message:

```
on beforeYouStartPlayingTheMovie
   start using stack "Widget Project"
end beforeYouStartPlayingTheMovie

-- in stack "Widget Project"
on playStopped
  if the id of the target is the id of player "Player" of stack "Your Stack" then
    -- do whatever you want here
  end if
  pass playStopped
end playStopped
```

Use the `playerFinished` message on iOS and Android.